# Unexpected tuple unpacking, possible scoping issue/confusion

Tags: python-3.x, scope, iterable-unpacking

I'm using python 3.6.

I'm really confused about the unpacking in line 09 and 10. I expect `dy_outer` on line 09 to equal (0, -1) and `dy_inner` on line 09 to equal (side-1, 0).  Similarly, I expect `dx_outer` and `dx_inner` on line 10 to equal (0, -1) and (side-1, 0) respectively.

However, when the set_trace goes off, instead I see that that values of `dy_outer` and `dy_inner` from line 09 are equal to 0 and -1 respectively.  And same goes with `dx_outer` and `dx_inner` from line 10; they're equal to 0 and -1 respectively as well.

`offsets` is a tuple of tuples, so when you iterate over it, it should unpack each tuple, not each element from the first tuple.

Is my intuition about Python scoping incorrect?

```py
01 def cover(board, lab = 1, top = 0, left =0, side = None):
02    if side is None:
03        side = len(board)
04    
05    s = side // 2
06    
07    offsets = (0, -1), (side-1, 0)
08    
09    for dy_outer, dy_inner in offsets:
10        for dx_outer, dx_inner in offsets:
11            set_trace()
12            if not board[top+dy_outer][left+dx_outer]:
13                board[top + s + dy_inner][left+s+dx_inner] = lab
14    lab += 1
15    if s > 1:
16        for dy in [0,s]:
17            for dx in [0, s]:
18                lab = cover(board, lab, top+dy, left+dx, s)
19    return lab
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mystery has three parts.  First, the offsets structure is a 2-D array:

```
((0, -1),
 (side-1, 0))
```

The second part is that the for-loop will loop only over the rows:

```
>>> for row in offsets:
        print(row)

(0, -1)
(18, 0)
```

The third part is that the unpacking just unpacks the columns on a given row:

```
>>> for column_zero, column_one in offsets:
        print('Column 0:', column_zero)
        print('Column 1:', column_one)
        print()

Column 0: 0
Column 1: -1

Column 0: 18
Column 1: 0
```

Putting the pieces together shows that your intuition was correct:

```
print('dy_o', 'dy_i', 'dx_o', 'dx_i', sep='\t\t')
print('----', '----', '----', '----', sep='\t\t')
for dy_outer, dy_inner in offsets:
    for dx_outer, dx_inner in offsets:
        print(dy_outer, dy_inner, dx_outer, dx_inner, sep='\t\t')
```

gives the expected output:

```
dy_o            dy_i            dx_o            dx_i
----            ----            ----            ----
0               -1              0               -1
0               -1              18              0
18              0               0               -1
18              0               18              0
```

Hope this takes the riddle out of the mystery, inside an enigma :-)

Comment: I got it.  Thank you!